# How to Implement expendables/collapsible views in android?

Tags: android

How to create a expendables/collapsible views like this?
I am not getting any idea after surfing, please give some ideas to implement this concepts

I want this:

[image]

Comment: It seems nothing more complex than a customized ExpandableListView.

Comment: yes use ExpandableListView as mentioned by Der Golem otherwise there are many other ways but those are more complex and error prone.So it's better to use ExpandableListView

Comment: @DerGolem , I know Expandable list view but here i need different child views of the list how to do this is my question? how can i do this pls help me

Comment: Simply too broad. You must do some research on customizing the  ExpandableListView. And figure out a way to change the children row layouts depending on some conditions (possibly, they will be **all the same**, with some Views which are `dinamically hidden/shown`).

Comment: To add to @DerGolem's comment: that's exactly what [`getChildTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildTypeCount%28%29) and [`getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildType%28int,%20int%29) in `BaseExpandableListAdapter` are for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [ExpandableListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). Let me know if this not worked.

Comment: I know Expandable list view but here i need different child views of the list how to do this is my question

Comment: You just override the Adapters `getChildView` and select Type and Move in their. Then you set the parts of your View to `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to ensure, the right kind of View is shown. I know it is not the only and best solution but it can do your work.

Comment: Or simply Inflate only that view which you want to add at this position.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelpYou extends ExpandableListActivity {
TextView button1;
private static final String NAME = "NAME";
private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";
private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog_YOUNAMEIT);
    button1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void  onClick(View v){   
        finish();}});

    List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
```

THIS IS THE START POINT OF "DIFFERENT VIEWS"

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        groupData.add(curGroupMap);
        String order =getString(R.string.order);
        curGroupMap.put(NAME, order);
        curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");

        List<Map<String, String>> children3 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        {
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children3.add(curChildMap);
         // curChildMap.put(NAME, "Child " + j);
            String order1 =getString(R.string.order1);
            curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN,  order1
                                       );
        }
        childData.add(children3);
    }
```

DO IT AGAIN TO PRODUCE ANOTHER VIEW

AND HERE IS YOUR ADAPTER

```
    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            R.layout.rowsimpleitemlist,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            R.layout.rowsimpleitemlist2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
            );
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}}
```

This code does almost exactly what you ask. I did some funky stuff with my adapter. You will have to make some changes to add those rows in Tab 2.